# Problematic Players Help (2/3); The Vanishing Veteran

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players

A follow on from [Problematic Players help (1/3); Newbie Declaring Solo](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113000/problematic-players-help-1-3-newbie-declaring-solo) . In that question, I covered one of the problematic players in my online group. But she's not the only problematic player, not by a long shot.

I should mention, because it's more relevant here: this group is scattered all over the world. We communicate using discord for OOC, and roll20 for IC. Everything is text.

The other problem player is the most (and only) experienced player in the group by several years... but they are also a sneaky powergamer, and often try to sneak around using whatever version of the rules suits whatever shenanigans they're up to. An example of this is rolling up their character when everyone else is made with point-buy, and then somehow (using a personal dice roller, no screenshots or even the slightest fanfare, of course) getting such good rolls that none of their stats started below **16** in the game. This was pretty quickly corrected when it was spotted, but **whenever I try to confront them on something, they have a tendency to vanish into thin air until the subject changes.** This makes it incredibly slow and painful to get anything from them.

What can I do to change this behaviour, or best confront it?

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't use the roll20 dice roller for character creation for that player, if rolling was going to be how the character was generated?  I don't understand the problem of hidden rolls.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Rolling was not going to be how the character was generated, we were using point-buy; he didn't ask me about this, nor did he do anything reaction-wise to indicate that he'd gotten such amazing rolls - it leads me to believe that he just made them up. I'll go into more  detail when I can post p3, but things started pretty ramshackle, and his character was rolled up while I was already leading the first session.

Answer (score 26):

## Talk (yes, this is getting repetitive, but that's the base answer for this sort of problem)

Does this player realize that he does things that puts him above others and *thereby takes away the spotlight and fun from others*?

You are playing a cooperative game where everyone is supposed to play an *important* role. Especially with new users like the one from your last question this is important. Someone who does everything different and suddenly gets the best magic items and has the highest stats and other stuff like that may make it un-fun for others - which is bad.

## You adjudicate the rules if *everyone* uses standard array/point buy/rolling then he will have to do so, too

It's your table, you adjudicate the rules. If you say everyone starts with the standard array stats then everyone starts with the standard array. Not some "Yeah, you can't see it, but I rolled really well and this is one of the methods described in the PHB". Make it easy for everyone - your new players are important here - to know how stuff works. The veteran can only do what you allow him to do and he should accept that and guide the others.

## Mention that he can't just ignore problems

Vanishing into thin air? Great, that means you are the only one who can say something about the matter. Go with standard array and according to what the PHB recommends for the class. (You might want to give him a warning, though.) If the player doesn't want to cooperate then they have to accept what you decide. The moment you do this they will come out and rant - which is the moment you explain to them that they have to *discuss* issues with you when they arise or otherwise you decide something to keep the game moving. You can't wait for them forever. This will happen one or two times and then the power gamer will realize that talking will give them more power than not talking.

Just keep in mind that they might try something cheesy when they ask you whether you could make a certain houserule. Don't be afraid to go back on houserules if they don't work in the game. "Yeah, I know, but that's far too powerful. We did it the last three sessions, but from next one on we will do it the old way."

Comment: In general, I’ve reeled him in on rules. I’ve stopped him from playing a homebrew class, for example, because I want the newbies to only have to learn the canon classes. Due to the somewhat ramshackle nature of this campaigns beginnings, I didn’t have as good a grip on the situation as I should have. Its more in hindsight, where he’s talking things out (“I’ll silver this thing even though I shouldn’t have the money”) without saying how he got the money, and then vanishing when I ask. Even when there is a good reason, it’s suspicious.

Comment: @Leafsw0rd He shouldn't vanish. If you ask him about it and he doesn't reply you can mention that you will retcon it if you don't get any feedback. If you really don't get any feedback you will retcon it. That's probably when he will come out of hiding and try to weasel himself out of the situation. If he can explain it and you believe he tells the truth just tell him that he shouldn't let you hang by not replying. If he can't explain it retcon it and give him a warning that you will not tolerate such behaviour anymore. Cheaters are never welcome (at least to my games).

Comment: If he gets away with his actions via "vanishing", they you're reinforcing that behavior. You don't have to be malicious, but you do have to be firm: It's classical conditioning: if something works, it'll be done more. So (when you see it) don't let it work.

Answer (score 15):

### Cheaters should get to cheat on their own

Once or twice can be a mistake, repeated offenses is cheating and should **NOT** be tolerated. I typically counsel prudence and seeking to improve through patient guidance. But from what I read here, you get a repeat offender on the cheat or cheat-like behavior.

The newbies are looking to him on how to play and the social conventions of gaming.

Kick him.

Comment: The problem is that that’s the only explicit case. In other ones, he’s bent or leant on the rules, but not really enough to call it anything other than a misconception.

Comment: @Leafsw0rd He creates a super character when everyone else uses a point buy = Cheating. Not engaging when confronting with odd situation is obscuring the truth = a form of cheating (I don't acknowledge things until they go away). From your post, his obscuring happened MORE THAN ONCE. Time to kick him to the curb so he can win at cheating without anyone calling him on it.